# Cannot setup the envirorment for ROS2 and try the example

Tags: ros2

After following the installation tutorial on ROS website (huble hawksbill version) step by step i'm trying to setup the environment for ROS2, but when i run the command
call C:\dev\ros2_humble\local_setup.bat

The answer is this:

"[rti_connext_dds_cmake_module][warning] RTI Connext DDS environment script not found (\resource\scripts\rtisetenv_x64Win64VS2017.bat). RTI Connext DDS will not be available at runtime, unless you already configured PATH manually."

I tried to install RTI Connext DDS separately but the result is the same